# RecordType Query Not Returning Correct Results in Test

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, record-type

I've started to notice that the `RecordType` table isn't handling limits correctly, but only in Test Classes.

If I run `[SELECT Id FROM RecordType]`, there are a bunch of results.
But If I run `[SELECT Id FROM RecordType LIMIT 1]`, the result is null.

Through some trial and error I discovered that it appears to be off by 2, meaning that if I run `[SELECT Id FROM RecordType LIMIT 3]`, I'll get one result back instead of 3 even though there are way more than 3 when I ran the query without the limit.

This appears to have started recently, but I can't seem to find anything that could have caused this change.  Is there something that I'm missing or some other way to fix it other than setting the limit to 3?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue. You might want to contact Support and see what they have to say; it may be specific to your org.

Comment: I'm seeing this on a Partner Dev Org, when issuing the SOQL in the Developer Console.  I created two record types, and see both when I don't use a limit, when I set it to limit 1 I get zero results, but like you when I set it to limit 3 I get one result.  Very curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known Salesforce bug](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018AzeQAE).

Comment: Should I post such information as a proper answer (as I've done here) or is a comment to the original question a better place?!

Comment: Interesting, it just started happening in my orgs recently.

Comment: Let me first of all state that I found this answer only by searching online (+some luck). I'm in no way an expert regarding this curious phenomenon ;-) One explanation for your case could obviously be that your profile access to objects has changed recently (but you might have thought of this already). Another explanation - that your org was not affected; from past experience I got the impression that Salesforce's list under "Is it fixed?" is a bit unreliable. (I assume the hosting machine of your org hasn't changed?! Probably not very probable.)